# Extract URL from a list of url in perl

Tags: regex, perl, url

using the following code im getting all the url in a site

```
while( $html =~ m/<A HREF=\"(.*?)\"/g ) {    
      print "$1\n";  
  }
```

which gives me all the URL . but my question is i wanna extract only the url ends with

1) .pdf

or

2)  .doc

for example

```
http://nc.casaforchildren.org/files/public/site/jobs/CSO.pdf
```

can any one help me thanks .

Comment: why are you searching for `"` ?

Comment: Im constructing a spider..

Comment: I assume you understand all the standard caveats about not parsing HTML with regular expressions, and have a good reason for ignoring them :-)

Comment: @DaveCross can you kindly explain me .

Comment: There's a really good explanation in the accepted answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @DaveCross  thank you lot. And i got some idea about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to search case insensitive:

```
while( $html =~ m/<A HREF="(.*?\.(?:pdf|doc))"/ig ) {    
    print "$1\n";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 m/<A HREF=\"(.*?(.pdf|.doc))\"/g
```

Its working at my place:

```
> cat temp
<A HREF="http://nc.casaforchildren.org/files/public/site/jobs/CSO.pdf">bwfjbwej</A>
<A HREF="http://nc.casaforchildren.org/files/public/site/jobs/CSO.xls">bwfjbwej</A>
<A HREF="http://nc.casaforchildren.org/files/public/site/jobs/CSO.doc">bwfjbwej</A>

> perl -lne 'print $1 if(/<A HREF=\"(.*?(.pdf|.doc))\"/g)' temp
http://nc.casaforchildren.org/files/public/site/jobs/CSO.pdf
http://nc.casaforchildren.org/files/public/site/jobs/CSO.doc
>
```

Comment: You have to escape the `.` otherwise it matches anything and not a literal dot before pdf|doc.

Comment: +1 you gave me a correct answer but it your answer is case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

If your grouping `(.*?)` matches all URLs, you should go with:

```
while( $html =~ m/<A HREF=\"(.*?(\.pdf|\.doc))\"/g ) {    
      print "$1\n";  
  }
```

Be aware that this matches also `.pdf` which might not be what you are searching. The pattern `.*?` is greedy and quite dangerous imo.

/edit

I tried it on http://regexpal.com/

```
\b(.*(\.pdf|\.doc))\b
```

for

```
http://nc.casaforchildren.org/files/public/site/jobs/CSO.pdf
http://nc.casaforchildren.org/files/public/site/jobs/CSO.doc
http://nc.casaforchildren.org/files/public/site/jobs/CSO.pdd
.pdf
http://nc.casaforchildren.org/files/public/site/jobs/CSO.pdfawd
```

It matches just the first two URLs.

Comment: What are you observing? It matches all URLs once again?

Comment: @bashophil.. i saw  a blank black screen

Comment: You could try `(.*\.pdf|.*\.doc)`. Btw I would suggest to add boundaries around your pattern: `\b`

Comment: +1 you gave me a correct answer but it your answer is case sensitive

Comment: @Backtrack the case sensitivity option will just add the tags `PDF` or `pDf` or something like this. I am not sure but I guess this is irrelevant. The stuff before `pdf` will match nevertheless because `.*` is greedy. Btw `.*?` is the same like `.*`. Anything matches zero times up to infinity times.

Comment: @bashophil in that page " A HREF"  and "a href"  both things are present in that case yours will fail actually mine too ,  so that only i accepted  M42's answer

Comment: No problem but we can't guess what's important for your specific problem. You have to describe it. Nonetheless, like I wrote, watch out for escaping the dot with `\.` otherwise it matches literally anything. Besides that I would suggest to use word boundaries (see my examples).